# JSON file to map

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a .json datastore and want to use `Map()` specific methods to get the values. 
Here is some example of my .json file:

```
"program": [
    {
        "name": "program1",
        "phases": [
            {
                "name": "A",
                "cycles": [
                    {
                        "name": "day 1",
                        "exercises": [
                            {
                                "name": "workout1",
                                "set": 4,
                                "repetitions": 8
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "workout2",
                                "set": 4,
                                "repetitions": 8
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My goal is to do something like this:

```
console.log(program.get("program1").phases.get("A").name);
```

I have a similar function which converts a .json file to a map

```
const datastore = require("./datastore.json");

function toMap(array, prop) {
    const map = new Map();
    for(const el of array) map.set(el[prop], el);
    return map;
}

var program = toMap(datastore, "name");
```

but this converts only one "Map-layer", so I can only perform one `.get()`, no deeper ones.

**Next thing is, that I want to modify the Map and save it back to the datastore.**

Comment: Why are you setting it to a `Map`?  Why not just iterated on the .json structure as it is with a `.forEach` loop?

Comment: Because I want to select values with `.get()` sometimes I need to do this 3 times in a row, I don't want to use 3 `.forEach`. I think a map, in this case, had a better performance than a forEach because my application needs a lot of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed some bugs from @Vipin Kumar's version:

```
function toMap(array, key) {
    const map = new Map();
    for(const element of array) {
        if (element[key]) {
            map.set(element[key], element);
        }
        for(var subkey in element) {
            if (Array.isArray(element[subkey])) {
                if (element[subkey][0][key]) {
                    element[subkey] = toMap(element[subkey], key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

It will only convert arrays with given key to a map, instead of converting every array to a map.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use recursion to fix your `toMap()` function. Please see fixed version below

```
function toMap(array, prop) {
    const map = new Map();
    for(const el of array) {
      map.set(el[prop], el);
      for(var key in el) {
        if (Array.isArray(el[key])) {
          el[key] = toMap(el[key], prop);
        }
      }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: how can I save the converted map back to the json file?

Comment: sorry, but the code above also converts arrays inside a map without the given prop.